# Are factory methods Expression.Parameter() and Expression.Variable() interchangeable?

Tags: c#, expression-trees

Based on the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd294144%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355908%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the two factory methods look interchangeable. Are they?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Expression.Parameter()` supports ByRef types (i.e. a `ref` parameter), while `Expression.Variable()` will throw an exception if given one.

They are otherwise identical, but that's an implementation detail and you shouldn't rely on it:

```
public static ParameterExpression Parameter(Type type, string name)
{
    bool isByRef = type.IsByRef;
    if (isByRef)
    {
        type = type.GetElementType();
    }
    return ParameterExpression.Make(type, name, isByRef);
}

public static ParameterExpression Variable(Type type, string name)
{
    if (type.IsByRef)
    {
        throw Error.TypeMustNotBeByRef();
    }
    return ParameterExpression.Make(type, name, false);
}
```